# Distance between a boat and a dock

Tags: functions, trigonometry

problem : A boat is tied to a dock by means of a cable 60m long. if the dock is 20 m above the water and if the cable is being drawn in the rate 10m/min, express the distance y m of the boat from the dock after t min.

I saw this problem in the first pages of a math book which was about functions. i know the answer notwithstanding i still can`t understand why ??? 
the answer is : $10\sqrt{t^2-12t+32}$

can any one help me to solve it (:

Comment: Pythagoras's theorem might help: you can find the length of the cable at time $t$ and the height of the dock (assuming no tide)

Comment: A non-calculation version of this question which I saw posed to primary-school children is whether the boat accelerates or decelerates as $t$ increases

Comment: The boat is moving towards the dock, but the cable is drawn through the air being the hypotenuse of the triangle

Comment: Yes you right, the question is really simple I thought that the cable is moving toward the water like a parabola but actually it is being drawn by someone on the dock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you right, the question is really simple I thought that the cable is moving toward the water like a parabola but actually it is being drawn by someone on the dock

$\sqrt{(60-(t*10))^2 - 20^2}$ = $\sqrt{3600+100t^2-1200t-400 }$ =$10\sqrt{t^2-12t+32}$